# C# application compiled with .NET SQLite driver?

Tags: .net, sqlite, driver

Real quick question! ***If I load an SQLite driver into my .NET project, when I save and compile this project (it's a simple Windows Forms application), will the SQLite driver form part of the application?** Basically I'm planning on having one of my form controls execute an SQL query on an SQLite database which will exist on a user's machine. Obviously if this driver does not exist then the SQLite database file will not be able to be interpreted!

Thanks for any input.

Comment: edited, sorry for poor clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume by driver you mean external DLL--something like the [ADO.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/) library.  You will need to distribute the DLL with your executable, or compile the source code directly into your solution.

You can also use [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) to merge the DLL into your executable after the fact.